# Returning multiple values with INDEX and MATCH without VBA

Tags: excel, indexing, match, vlookup

While i have seen this topic answered before i cant seem to understand the solution :(

Here is my worksheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0AsCQyX3EZ40SdC1FNFBjVDh6d01iY2g0WnVXOU5GeFE&output=xls

As you can see i need the second INDEX in the first sheet to return the second value looked, but instead (as expected) it shows the first one again.

I am not the best with excel, explain slowly and i will understand fast!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would use a pivot table on your data and set the searchName as the Report Filter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this "array formula" in Calculator sheet cell A3

`=IFERROR(INDEX(IngredientDB!B$1:B$100,SMALL(IF(IngredientDB!$A$1:$A$100=$B$1,ROW(IngredientDB!$A$1:$A$100)),ROWS(A$3:A3))),"")`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> and copied across and down. When you run out of entries you get blanks - assumes up to 100 rows of data, increase as required

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to go the pivot table route you can start with this as a base and then customize it to your exact liking.:

Start with your info:

[image]

Then add a pivot of your data:

[image]

Then set the properties as so and then you can select the search terms, you can also change the settings to allow someone to type it in also:

The result will be as so:

[image]

Comment: While this works i wanted to make a dynamic table and not turn to PIVOT every time i need to look for something :) - barry houdini's answer was perfect for the case