# Index Match - Return Multiple Values

Tags: excel, indexing, matching

I am new to index match as I just downloaded Excel 2016 and I am beyond lost.

For context, I will be adding my formula to cell Q3 and dragging it down. Sheet 2 runs from A1-N25435

I am trying to look up an ID Number (sheet 1, column B) and return of the requisition number(s) (sheet 2, column D) associated with that candidate ID (Sheet 2, Column C). I run into issues as there could be up to 20 requisitions associated with a specific ID and I can't seem to get any data to return.

Ideally, this information is returned horizontally.

If anyone could provide assistance I would be most appreciative.

edit: I tried this match formula that works but only returns ones of the results. I am looking to return all of the values. =MATCH(B3,'Sheet2'!$C$1:$C$25435,0)

I then tried:
=IF(ISERROR(INDEX($A$1:$N$25435,SMALL(IF('[Sheet2]Candidate ID'!!$A$1:$N$25435=$Q$3,ROW($A$1:$N$25435)),ROW(1:1)),2)),"",INDEX([Sheet2A$1:$N$25435,SMALL(IF($A$1:$N$25435=$D$1,ROW($A$1:$N$25345)),ROW(1:1)),2)) which yielded no result.

Comment: Can you post the formula(s) you have tried so far? You may also want to add the "Excel" tag to your question

Comment: (Please [*edit*](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51678248/edit) you question with the additional info, it will make it easier for everyone to get all the relevant info.)

Comment: YOu may want to check [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19642462/returning-multiple-values-with-index-and-match-without-vba) out

Comment: Thanks - I've looked at all of them and have tried to duplicate them for my data but it never seems to work

Answer (score 0):

Try this in Q3 and fill down until you run out of requisition numbers to return,

```
=iferror(index('sheet2'!d:d, aggregate(15, 7, row($1:$25435)/('sheet2'!c$1:c$25435=b$3), row(1:1))), text(,))
```

Comment: Thanks so much - this only seemed to return one of the requisitions and not all of the requisitions. Is it possible I am doing something incorrect still?

Comment: The problem may be with your data. That works for me based on simple sample data I made up according to your description. Post redacted sample data to a shared google-sheet or shared excel online workbook and edit your question to include the share link.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend the youtube videos by [excelisfun]. He has great tutorials and example work to learn from. He covers everything from the very basic to the very advanced and shows you how to logic your way through the pieces.

While I recognize that this is not exactly what you are looking for, this problem has presented several times until I got tired of trying to do array formulas and small to do the work. I wrote 3 functions that split the cell on a delimiter before running countif, index, and match on each row in the cell. It also works when there is a single entry.

To use these functions add them to the personal workbook and then they will be available in the functions - user defined functions area and allow you to use the wizzard to complete the entries.

Creating a personal workbook: [Robust Instructions](https://trumpexcel.com/personal-macro-workbook/)
Slimline: To get to the personal workbook, use the little record macro button in the bottom left corner of excel, do a thing like type in a box and press enter, then stop recording the macro. It will ask you where to save it and select personal workbook. If it does not exist yet it should create it for you. Then you can edit that macro you just created and paste the functions over the top of the one you just made.

Note: in the match function I presume a matchtype of exact match because that is all I ever do. It would be reasonably easy to add a 4th argument if you need to pass that in as well.

```
    Public Function StackCountIf(lookup_value, lookup_array, delimiter)
        If (Len(lookup_value) - Len(Replace(lookup_value, delimiter, "")) = 0) Then
            StackCount = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(lookup_array, lookup_value)
        Else
            arrLookup = Split(lookup_value, delimiter)
            For Each thisLookup In arrLookup
                thisReturn = thisReturn + WorksheetFunction.CountIf(lookup_array, thisLookup)
            Next thisLookup
            StackCount = thisReturn
        End If
    End Function

    Public Function StackMatch(lookup_value, lookup_array, delimiter)
        If (Len(lookup_value) - Len(Replace(lookup_value, delimiter, "")) = 0) Then
            StackMatch = WorksheetFunction.Match(lookup_value, lookup_array, 0)
        Else
            arrLookup = Split(lookup_value, delimiter)
            For Each thisLookup In arrLookup
                thisReturn = thisReturn & WorksheetFunction.Match(thisLookup, lookup_array, 0) & delimiter
            Next thisLookup
            thisReturn = Left(thisReturn, (Len(thisReturn) - Len(delimiter)))
            StackMatch = thisReturn
        End If
    End Function

    Public Function StackIndex(lookup_array, row_num, delimiter)
        If (Len(row_num) - Len(Replace(row_num, delimiter, "")) = 0) Then
            StackIndex = WorksheetFunction.Index(lookup_array, row_num)
        Else
            arrRownums = Split(row_num, delimiter)
            For Each thisRownum In arrRownums
                thisReturn = thisReturn & WorksheetFunction.Index(lookup_array, thisRownum) & delimiter
            Next thisRownum
            thisReturn = Left(thisReturn, (Len(thisReturn) - Len(delimiter)))
            StackIndex = thisReturn
        End If
    End Function
```