# Excel formula to get unique value from a lookup only if all values match

Tags: excel-formula, lookup-tables

I'm trying to find a way to perform an INDEX MATCH lookup that goes beyond the first match to check if all matching values are equivalent. I've found [formulas that will return all matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51678248/index-match-return-multiple-values), but what I'd like to do is have the matching value returned in the formula cell, but only if all values returned are the same.

Here's an example:

[image]

I'm matching the report number with the report number below and only picking up the area value if all report-area combinations are the same. Is there a clean way to do this?

Comment: You can do this through multiple steps, maybe, but that will be a difficult nested function to interpret.  Have you considered a UDF?  Also, I think your "12378" example is bad, it doesn't exist in the example set.

Comment: Thanks for catching that. Okay, I'll try to accomplish this in separate steps. I'm not too familiar with user-defined functions.

Comment: With UDFs you can use code to algorithmically perform the steps.  With an array of nested formulas it looks messy and can require you maintain some of the middle steps in the sheet, as the answer below illustrates.

Answer (score 1):

Dan.

My solution may seem a bit messy, but you can make it simpler as you go, once you start implementing it:

[image: I'll paste the formulas in plain text]

First, I made a *Report* Count. (How many 12345 Reports are there in total, and so on).

```
 =COUNTIF($A$2:$A$10;A2)
```

Then, I concat the Report-Area to get a unique identifier for every Report-Area combination.

```
=A2&"-"&B2
```

Now, I make a Count of that column, meaning I count how many combinations are there for each case (e.g. how many 12345-2C are there in total).

```
 =COUNTIF($D$2:$D$10;D2)
```

Then, I create an "Ok" Column for checking if the *Report Count* matches the *Concat Count*.

```
=IF(C2=E2;"OK";"")
```

That said, we have our table ready for checking what you're looking for.

In just one formula (the one under Lookup header) on cell B13:

```
=IF(INDEX(F2:F10;MATCH(A13;A2:A10;0))="OK";INDEX(B2:B10;MATCH(A13;A2:A10;0));"")
```

- I check IF there's an "OK" on the *OK* column for that *Report* number.
- If there is, I Search for the "*Area*" value for that *Report* number.
- If there isn't an "OK", I leave a blank cell. (In your example, it's #N/A)

The formulas on H2, I2 and C13 are just for reference. Plain text.

Again, I know it seems messy, but if you're not too familiar with some Excel formulas and functions, this is a good way to learn and build complex formulas step by step (Just as our fellow n8 said)

I assume you understand how INDEX MATCH works. If you don't, I'll edit an explanation for you.

Good Luck!

Comment: This is what I meant about needing multiple steps to accomplish the goal.  Kudos for laying it all out, I didn't have the patience :P

Comment: Thanks francovici for the very detailed explanation. I understand INDEX MATCH well enough to implement this. I'm just happy that this can be accomplished without array functions.